# pylance `unresolved import` error on selecting conda as python interpreter

Tags: python, pylance

I'm using vscode and using pylance for linting in python I get an error while I'm trying to import restframework:

`Import "rest_framework.decorators" could not be resolved`

I get this error when I select a conda environment as my python interpreter but if I select the default python path as my interpreter I don't get this error.

***Why do I get such type of error only when I select conda environment as my interpreter path***

Please help me by answering.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the package you are importing installed in the environment you have selected. From the above, it sounds like you have it installed in the global Python environment but not in your conda environment. Try selecting your conda environment, then open a terminal pane in Visual Studio Code and 'conda install' the package and see if that helps (although you may need to reload the editor or toggle out and back in to the environment to pick up the change).